# Cheerio Binance Leaderboard scrape

Tags: web-scraping, cheerio

Hello I am trying to scrape some leaderboard postions from several traders.

Somehow I can catch all contents from tables all around the internet but not from this very Binance site, somehow I do not get any return. I dont even get a response how many table rows there are in this code snippet. Is something different with the table on the traders positons? I dont really know why I cant scrape this very data.

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const express = require("express")

async function getTradeFeed() {
    try {
        const siteUrl = "https://www.binance.com/en/futures-activity/leaderboard?type=myProfile&encryptedUid=CCF3E0CB0AAD54D9D6B4CEC5E3E741D2"

        const { data } = await axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: siteUrl,
        })

        const $ = cheerio.load(data)
        const elemSelector = '#__APP > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.css-gnqbje > div.css-1bypc10 > div > div.css-2a3hpu > div > div > div > table > thead > tr'
        
        $(elemSelector).each((parentIdx, parentElem) => {
            console.log(parentIdx)
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

getTradeFeed();
```

Comment: Cheerio is not able to load AJAX content, which is how that data is loaded. Look for ways to make the AJAX request instead of trying to parse the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [API](https://rapidapi.com/DevNullZero/api/binance-futures-leaderboard1/). And its [documentation](https://github.com/Nunnito/Binance-Futures-Leaderboard-API).

This is a sample code that gets all positions from `CCF3E0CB0AAD54D9D6B4CEC5E3E741D2` trader:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://binance-futures-leaderboard1.p.rapidapi.com/v1/getOtherPosition',

  params: {
    encryptedUid: 'CCF3E0CB0AAD54D9D6B4CEC5E3E741D2',
    tradeType: 'PERPETUAL'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'binance-futures-leaderboard1.p.rapidapi.com',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'YOUR-API-KEY'
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```